# Linker Error while importing third party project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, linker

I am importing a third party project, which has its own framework. I wish to study that API, when I am trying to open that project, I am getting

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_T0Command", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_T1Command", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_iSmart", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have spent almost one and half hour searching for the solution.

`Link Binaries with Libraries` contains the desired framework, it was missing initially I have **already added**

The project has been build and clean several times.

**EDIT 1**
I have  run the 'file' command using terminal on the binary of the framework

```
file iSmartSDK
iSmartSDK: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
iSmartSDK (for architecture armv7): Mach-O object arm
iSmartSDK (for architecture armv6): Mach-O object arm
```

Comment: I have the same issue. iSmart sdk provider should build their framework for i386 too. We have to tell them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the framework is only compiled for ARM, and not for Intel ( i386 ). Try running it on your iPhone and see what happens..

alternatively you can run the 'file' command using terminal on the binary of the framework to check and see what architectures it supports. Is the 3rd party framework opensource? you should probably download the source, include it in your project and compile it every time you build your project so you won't have such issues..

Comment: @onkar as you can see it only has ARM binaries, you won't be able to run this on the simulator without recompiling that framework, this is your entire problem.

Comment: Thank You. Can I deploy the app directly onto iPhone then ?

Comment: @onkar if you are able to do so, yes.. you will need a developer account for this though.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `ViewController.m` is not added into the `target's` `compiled source`s in `build phases`.

Update 1: set "Build Active Architectures Only" to yes.

`Target` --> `Build Settings`

Update 2: Check that you have not written `#import "ViewController.m"`. !!

Comment: I have  set `Build Active Architectures Only` to `yes` but still the same problem